# Laravel models usage

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have recently started using the PHP framework Laravel, and built some web apps using it.

On the Laravel Documentation, it says that models makes it easier to query data from our database and insert data into our database. But I made some apps (albeit, the apps I made were pretty small since they were strictly for learning purposes), and I didn't really use Models. I built the ER using MySQL Workbench, and forward engineered it to get my database and I worked on from there, making 0 models.

My question is, why is it recommended that we use Models when interacting with our database? Do models make it easier when size of the project increases?

I just want to learn it the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are Laravel advantages when using Models (Eloquent):

1. Relationships and Eager loading
2. Mutators
3. Scopes (local and global)
4. Route model buinding

Any way, working through models makes your code more structural, you reduce code duplicates, you can make unit tests, all routine work done by framework. And that is MUST HAVE for today.

Just try to use it and you will understand how it is awesome.

I would recommend you to check this: https://laracasts.com

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Igor. I certainly will use models from now on. Just to clarify one last thing, a Model and a migration file go hand in hand, right? Having a migration file without the model (or vice versa) is of little use, right?

Comment: You can use migrations separately, as migrations are not only for creating tables, but also for alters, adding indexes to tables, sometimes data updating.

Comment: Cool, man.. Thanks for all your help. You gave me the answers I needed